# Android monkey testing onClick command

Tags: android, onclick, action, touch-event, monkeyrunner

I found monkey test tool.
I used this command:

```
monkey -p package1 -p package2 --pct-touch 100 --throttle 40 --ignore-crashes --ignore-timeouts --monitor-native-crashes --hprof -v 3000000 | tee /mnt/shared/logs/monkey_14062013_1.logp
```

I got success to get touch event.

1.Monkey found `"ACTION_UP" & "ACTION_DOWN"` . Is there any command to protect only one event?
2.Monkey any particular command to use only `onClick` event.

Thanks,

Comment: if it's still actual, there are more options for monkey tool. you need ```--pct-motion <percent>``` to increase motion events count. http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkey.html

Comment: @shomeser read question again. --pct-motion<percent> only for particular event, but actoin_up & action_down is also there for same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Presses the Menu button

device.press('KEYCODE_MENU', MonkeyDevice.DOWN_AND_UP)

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Open command prompt

Step 2: Move to Android SDK folder -- platforms-tools -- where adb command run

Step 3: Copy following command:

```
adb -e shell monkey --ignore-crashes -p packagename 500 ＞ test_logs.txt
```

After successful done we can check logs in
Path To Android SDK `/platforms-tools/test_logs.txt`